# Android Studio upgrade automatic to 2.1 from 1.5 won't work

Tags: android-studio, upgrade

Ever since version 2.0 there is no way that I can get the button "Update and Restart" back when checking for updates.  This missed button downloaded and applied automatically the patch to the newer version. It stopped working when 2.0 came to be. I am currently on 1.5, and would like to get 2.1 but not downloading the zip.

Now all I get is this, which forces me to download the zip file, but doesn't install the application.  I have seen other posts related but none of them have solved my problem.

[image: Studio Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no `Update and restart` button from 1.5 to 2.0. You need to go to [download page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and download the newest version --> 2.1. If you had a version 2.0 and you want to upgrade to 2.1, the functionality of downloading & restarting would be fully operational.

The differences between 1.5 and 2.0 are too major just to download a patch and update your old Android Studio. [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/studio.html) you have all revisions and changes.

You can still add your settings from the previous Android Studio, so there should be no problem for you.

Comment: My concern is that the zip dowloaded contains a folder with the full IDE in, but not exe file to install it properly in /Program Files. How should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: You need to go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#downloads and choose option: `android-studio-ide-143.2790544-windows.exe` for the version without SDK included or `android-studio-bundle-143.2790544-windows.exe` with SDK included.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. I had an `Update and restart` button on my Android Studio 1.5 and I used it to upgrade to 2.0.

Comment: @AlvaroGutierrezPerez No, it is not wrong. At least for Mac version, there was no Update and restart button.

Comment: @mmBs I disagree. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37302767/5373629) for possible expanations if it doesn't appeared for you.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I just had to close that dialog and click again on Check for Updates until 'Update and Restart' appeared. I had to re open the dialog like 3 times. 
I had 1.5.1 and updated to 2.1.1

Comment: This worked for me. Several reloads of the updates window, and one restart of Android studio, and the Update and Restart button eventually showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to install Android Studio from a .zip folder:

If you have Windows:

1. Open the .zip folder using Windows Explorer.
2. Click on 'Extract all' (or 'Extract all files') option in the ribbon.
3. Enter any extract location you like. Extract them.
4. Go to the extract location. Go to `android-studio\bin` and run
   `studio.exe`.
5. Go through the installation wizard. You are done

If you have any other OS:

1. Go [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or [here](https://unzip-online.com/en/Zip) (the second link is preferred).
2. If you chose the first link then run application and unzip your
   folder. If you chose the second link then upload your file, get it
   unzipped and download it.
3. Go to the extract/download location. Go to `android-studio\bin` and
   run the studio executable for your OS.
4. Go through the installation wizard. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

My Android Studio was 1.5.1. After closing the dialog 2 times and checking again for the update solved the issue. Got the "Update and Restart" button 3rd time